# Looking for a light-weight cross-platform C threading library

Tags: c, multithreading

I wanted to use OpenMP for this, but it is not appropriate for my purposes: creating my own thread pool.

So, this needs to be C89 code with, of course, platform specific code for windows and unices.

I need this for a C only library, so no C++, boost C++11, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that you are asking this question.  Usually it's people who don't have significant experience on StackOverflow and who don't understand what is considered [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: try Apache Portable Runtime (APR). It has a threading library: http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__thread__proc.html

Comment: Thanks, bruceg. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Use POSIX Threads - pthread. There is Windows implementation.

Also take a look on GThread - part of Glib.

Comment: Thanks, Kyrylo. I found this library   https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool - pthreads only ,but I may adapt to windows

Comment: +1 GThread works great for me. The only downside is no "kill", apparently there is no cross platform way to kill a thread.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, jforberg.